# How to setup a Google funnel for the same url?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to setup Google Funnel for a website which works with one checkout page with 5 different steps (all loaded via Ajax through button).

I'm trying to understand how it has to be setup so i can see in my Google Analytics account.
I just don't understand the following part and how it has to be done :

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#identical

Does anyone can help me ?

I guess i have to add an event for instance :

```
onclick=”billing.save(); javascript: ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘/checkout/billing_details/’);“
```

Then google will do the job for me ?

Comment: Yup, that code is 80% of what you need to do! Just do that for each step, and then you also need to go to your checkout goal in GA admin (create the goal if you don't have it) and set up the funnel within the Goal config.

Answer (score 0):

The premise here is that with AJAX content, your url doesn't change. To get around this, you need to send a virtual page view which mimics an actual page view each time new content is loaded. The code you referenced does exactly that - it sends a virtual page view using the command

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/funnel/step1.html');
```

where the virtual page path of `/funnel/step1.html` is used in the optional third parameter. This path can really be anything you want it to be, so something like this

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/vpv/your/new/path');
```

would also work.

This and any virtual page view needs to be sent when your new content is loaded, so on the Ajax request. Your example looks fine I think, but you should test it out and check with either real time, or with GA Debugger for Chrome.